# org-mode still indents content while I try to set it up not to

Tags: org-mode, indentation

I set `org-adapt-indentation` to `headline-data`

When I select a region under a headline (separated by a blank line) and press TAB, the paragraph gets indented at the same level as the headline title, as if I had set `org-adapt-indentation` to `t`.  I would expect all text to have zero indentation. Am I missing something ?

I'm using org 9.5.2 and emacs 28.1